# Error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from java.lang.String to int

Tags: java, string

I am new to Java and this is regarding the homework I have to do for my class. I am not sure what is the problem here or how to solve it. I appreciate it if someone can help me out.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class TravelAgent
 {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.print("Enter the amount per night");
       int lodging = input.nextInt();
       System.out.print("Enter your age");
       int age = input.nextInt();
    }

    public static int getLodging(int lodging, int age)
    {
       String message;

       if(lodging <= 30)
          message="campaign"; 
       else if(lodging <=45  && lodging > 30)
       {
          if(age <= 30)
              message="youth hotel";
          else if(age>30)
              message="adult hotel";
       }
       else if(lodging <=100 && lodging >45)
          message =  "hotel";
       else if(lodging <=200 && lodging >100)
          message="Grand hotel";
       else
          message="Exclusive suite";
      return message;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The return type of the method is int whereas you are returning "message" which is a string. This is causing the compiler to fail the conversion from String to int

Answer (score 0):

Your method returns **int** but you return message which is **String**

public static ***int*** getLodging(int lodging, int age)

***String*** message;

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the **getLodging** method as follows

```
public static String getLodging(int lodging, int age)
{
    String message = null;

    if(lodging <= 30)
    .
    .
    .
    return message;
}
```

And also you have to call this method in **main** to get the result.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // Get inputs lodging and age
    String result = getLodging(lodging, age);
    System.out.println("You're eligible for : "+result); // Print the result
}
```